# d3 scatterplot circles rendering differently on update

Tags: javascript, d3.js, meteor

Here I have the code for my scatterplot.
https://github.com/laran/eisenhower/blob/master/components/plot/scatterplot.js

This is what the plot looks like when it is initially rendered which is done by calling .setup() and then .update().
[image]

This is what the plot looks like **after a point is added (data points changed and plot updated)**.[image]

You'll notice that in addition to there being one more point on the second plot, while the new circle has a black outline, all of the circles that were already there have had their black outline removed.

My question is **why do the black circle outlines disappear after update**?

**And, for bonus points**:
After updating one of the data points and calling Application.Plotter.update(), the dots often don't update. Why don't the circles update after changing the data values and calling Application.Plotter.update()?

I have a feeling that there's something of in how I'm calling enter() or exit() on the plot. But I'm not familiar enough with d3 to really understand what I've done wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by calling .exit().remove() before calling .enter().append().

https://github.com/laran/eisenhower/commit/4a23906f17723449a5f1d4901279d32cbcf26870